# .htaccess help! redirecting URL with query string to root

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I'm new to htaccess so please bear with me.. 
I'm trying to redirect traffic to URLs with query string to the root of my site as these URLs are no longer used.

Here is an example:

I would like traffic to this URL

```
https://www.DomainName.com/subdir1/subdir2/cond_e.asp?obark=110246
```

to go to `http://www.DomainName.com`
I do not need to keep the URL or anything just redirect to my homepage.

I need to do this for query string value from obark=110246 all the way up to obark=120000.

I've basically played around with the below to get at least one URL to redirect properly but never could get it to work at all.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^oPark=110246$

RewriteRule ^subdir1/subdir2/cond_e(.*) ^$? [NE, R=301, L]
```

What am I doing wrong? please help!

Answer (score 0):

Try with below rule in subdir2,

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/cond_e.asp
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^obark=[1]{1}[1-2]{1}[0]{1}[02-9]{1}[094-5]{1}[06-9]{1}
RewriteRule ^ http://www.DomainName.com? [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks Abhishek Gurjar for the reply, I tried the above and when I browsed to the URL it redirected me to www.DomainName.com/subdir1/subdir2/index_e.asp is there a way to have this work by putting the rewriterule at the root level htaccess?

Comment: I put it in subdir2

Comment: Check if some other rule is not conflicting because it is working here http://htaccess.mwl.be?share=efcd0c32-159d-5bb6-ab69-bb08bd6d692a

Comment: hmm very strange, while it works in the htaccess tester, it's not working when I put the same conditions and rule in my htaccess.  I even tried few other variants of the conditions and they work in the tester and not in with my site.. I've also gone over to check for any conflicts but I didn't see any..